# What are the charge/power connector of restaurant order pagers / buzzers called?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, industrial-engineering, circuit-design, connections

They look like snap buttons and used for stacking pagers for charging.

Closest things I can find are socket screws and cap nuts.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pins appear to be pogo pins or spring loaded pins

[image]

Below are example of pogo pins

[image]

[image]

The following appear to be [swage mount](https://www.google.com/search?bih=680&biw=1424&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS892US892&hl=en&ei=IR8jYPz4Jaa7ggfXvKG4Dg&q=swage%20mount%20pcb%20pins&oq=Swage%20Mount%20&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgIIADIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46BwgAEEcQsANQ2OcBWNjnAWCB_QFoAXACeACAAVuIAZgBkgEBMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab) connectors

[image]

Here is an example

[image]

---

**Reference:**

- [Mill-max](https://www.mill-max.com/about)
- [How to pair the Retekess SU-668 Restaurant Paging System](https://youtu.be/jDT_uRF3Klw)

Comment: Thanks cuz!  Swage mount was exactly what I was looking for.